# Preserving mountpoint names in the Finder for NFS shares

Tags: finder, nfs

I am mounting a number of NFS shares, with a Terminal command akin to this:

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o soft,resvport,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=900,retrans=3,proto=tcp,nobrowse crbn-store-02.hectic.local:/mnt/raid/ /mnt/crbn-projects
```

The directory for the mount point ("/mnt/crbn-projects") is in place, and the mount command completes succesfully. However, the Finder shows me the name of the NFS directory on the server instead of the name of the mountpoint (it shows "raid" instead of "crbn-projects"). How can I force the Finder to not apply the "beautified" NFS directory names and sticking to the mount point names instead? In the terminal and on the FS all my mountpoints are named properly.